# Deleting accounts kept inactive for 45 days

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

In my project I wanna automatically delete accounts that are kept inactive for more that 45days. For testing purpose I took 2 minutes and wrote the following code. But its not working. Can anybody tell me how to perform "Record deletion" if kept inactive for 2 minutes.

My code follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=inactive;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*********;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        try
        {
            MyConnection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE name FROM email WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MIN)", MyConnection);
            MyConnection.Close();
            Label1.Text = "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=inactive;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*********;" + "OPTION=3";
            OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
            try
            {
                MyConnection.Open();
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select name from email where email=?", MyConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                   Response.Write(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
    }
}
```

---

---

Updated:

First I created a database named `inactive` and created a table `email`. The below screenshot says the record.

[image]

Later I used the following code..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=inactive;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=******;" + "OPTION=3";
    OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
    try
    {
        MyConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM email WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)", MyConnection);
        MyConnection.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DELETE` syntax seems to be wrong, drop the field name "name", ie

```
DELETE FROM email WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

(the `delete` command deletes whole row, not a single field)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `date` in backticks in the query, like so:

```
"DELETE FROM email WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)"
```

Of course it would be even better to **not** name a field `date` but something more descriptive like `lastchange`.

Comment: Not working. what is `date` here? do I need add anything called `date` in database table?

Comment: @Kars The "date" is from your original query! We all assumed its a field in the table, storing the "last active" timestamp. Yes you have to have sucha a field in your table (and you have to update it appropriately too) to achieve what you want!

Comment: @Ain, Johon - Sorry sorry, I didn't do that. Let me try now.

Comment: @Kars, note that the field needs to be of type `timestamp`, (don't name it that though because `timestamp` is a reserved word.)

Comment: `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM email WHERE 'date' < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)", MyConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.Date, 255).Value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: In database I created a field with name `date` and type is `timestamp`

Comment: @Kars, BACKTICKS ` not normal quotes.

Comment: @Kars Did you also filled the field with (meaningful) data? And why didn't you follow Johan's advise about choosing field name?

Comment: @ain - Well, I created some field with name `date` and type as `timestamp` and timestamp is changing on every update and currently has some value

Comment: finally this is the code I used in my page `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM email WHERE 'date' < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)", MyConnection);`

Comment: I am using back tricks my code. but to display her I used single quote

Comment: @Kars so in order the DELETE to actually delete those rows the values in the field must be older than 2 minutes (or whatever interval you use). Or do you get some error (in that case whats the message)?

Comment: @ain, johan - Sorry dude. its working. The problem is I didn't close the odbc command with `)` now it works... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **MIN** you should use **MINUTE** so:

```
DELETE FROM email WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Not working. what is `date` here? do I need add anything called `date` in database table?